# Kotlin : Interface with immutable property implemented by class with mutable

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

- Works around a limitation in Spring where @ConfigurationProperties classes need to follow the JavaBeans convention with mutable properties.

**Instead of inject the mutable TokenConfigurationConfig we inject the interface.**

```
public interface TokenAuthenticationConfig {

    public fun apiKey() : String

}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.api")
public open class TokenAuthenticationConfigImpl : TokenAuthenticationConfig
{
    public var apiKey : String

    constructor() {
        this.apiKey = ""
    }

    override fun apiKey(): String
    {
        return this.apiKey
    }
}
```

It works ok, but just wondering:

- Is it possible in Kotlin to define an interface with an immutable property, that is implemented by class with a mutable property.

Uses of the interface would see the property as immutable, while users of the class would see it as mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it definitely is possible to define such an interface and a class.

Any (publicly visible) property `x` in Kotlin means a pair of methods `getX()` and `setX(..)`, generated by the compiler to satisfy the Java convention. That said, it is consistent that you can override `getX` in a class and add `setX`.

Here is an example:

```
interface SomethingImmutable {
    val Somevar: String
}

class MyClass: SomethingImmutable {
    override var Somevar: String = "Initial Value"
}
```

Comment: Indeed it works, and also forces you to acknowledge intention by adding the 'override' modifier (I was missing this before).